# Retrieve data from Firestore, and setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

[image: Firestore collection]

```
export class Diet extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loaded: false,
          Ft: 0,
        };
      }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    await firebase.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.setState({
            Ft: users.Ft,
          });
        } else {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
  }
```

Hello, I am trying to retrieve the `Ft` from my Firestore document and store the value in `this.state`, so afterward I can use it in an expression later on on the page, any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Error: `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: _firebase.default.firestore.collection is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.firestore.collection("users")', '_firebase.default.firestore.collection' is undefined)]`

Comment: Did you try consoling `doc.data`? `Firebase` returns an `array of objects` inside `data`. You can check what's being returned and do `console.log(doc.data)` to see what's being returned and that will help you know how to access your `data`.

Comment: Try looking at doc.data

Comment: I am very new to programming and react native, and firebase, it'd be of great help if you could give me an example of how I can do it? At the moment I'm not even sure the code is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    firebase.firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.setState({
            Ft: doc.data().Ft
          });
        } else {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in import firebase, it gives me this error : 'TypeError:_firebase.default.firestore.collection is not a function'. I am using `import firebase from 'firebase';`

Comment: Please edit the error message into your question (there's an edit link right under it), as as the stack trace and the minimal code with which you can create the error. In general, I highly recommend spending some time learning about [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains great guidance on how to maximize the chances that someone can help you.

Comment: I will, thanks, I edited the post with error on the bottom

Comment: Ah, you were missing `()` after `firestore()`. See my updated answer, but also please check the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

You can try consoling your returned data to know what `firestore` is returning. Another mistake that you're doing is that you're using `await` together with `then/catch` and they don't work together in the same function. Run this snippet to correct the mistake and check the console for what `firestore` is actually returning.

```
export class Diet extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          loaded: false,
          Ft: 0,
        };
      }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    firebase.firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
         console.log(doc.data());
//As you're expecting to get Ft then you can set the state like this
          this.setState({
            Ft: doc.data().Ft
          });
        } else {
          alert("error");
        }
      });
  }}
```

or use `try/catch`

```
export class Diet extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loaded: false,
        Ft: 0,
      };
    }

async componentDidMount() {
  const id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

  let fetchedData = await firebase.firestore.collection("users").doc(id).get()

    try {
        if(fetchedData.exists){
            console.log(fetchedData.data());
//As you're expecting to get Ft then you can set the state like this
          this.setState({
            Ft: doc.data().Ft
          });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        
        alert("error", error);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: When I run it says 'Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection'. Type Error:! firebase.default.firestore.collection is not a function

Comment: I've updated the answer. Let me know if the problem is fixed.

Comment: That should be `doc.data()`, as [`DocumentSnapshot.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) is a method.

Comment: I had made a typo in the codes. Thank you very much for pointing it out @FrankvanPuffelen.